# Call to external API takes long when connected in local network?

Tags: networking, network-programming

I have 2 PCs that are connected in the same local network and they are connected to the same WiFi as well.

I have a web application that makes both of them communicate through a websocket (thanks to the local network). 
Also, one of the PC makes call to an external API. This call takes at least 10 seconds (TTFB) (through WiFi connection). So I tried to unplug ethernets from the switch and it seems to solve the problem. Calls are now fast.

But I need this local network as well (for the web socket). Could it come from the switch which is sort of broke?

How can we explain this behavior?

Comment: It's perhaps a routing  problem. Are ethernet IPs and wi-fi IPs on the same subnet, e.g. 192.168.1.0/24? Try the opposite, disconnect from wifi and make the call through ethernet.

Comment: The switch isn't connected to a router

Comment: It's mostly a routing problem then, what about the subnets? Are they different? you may need to tune your network config.

Comment: @LuisMuñoz They are different. WiFi IP : 192.168.0.16 and Ethernet IP: 172.16.0.68

Comment: And what is the gateway IP?